# Page is still loading after ng-repeat last item event done

Tags: jquery, angularjs

If I put more text with table in `ng-repeat` item, the page shows loading status even after rendering the last `ng-repeat` item. Certainly, I can't scroll down or see hover buttons or can't do anything when page stopping. I faced this problem in complex code from my project local.

I need to show loading page until really done loading page, not after last item in ng-repeat.

[Check the plnkr here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/XaQJ8rvwLUA1JHWUr8KB?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

add $timeout to directive and scope.$last event:

```
app.directive('myRepeatTrigger',['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $timeout(function () {
      if (scope.$last){
        alert('stop loading page');
      }
    });
  };
}]);
```